# Unable to concat dataframes - MemoryError

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, parquet, pyarrow

I am having an issue concatenating two dataframes. The strange part is that it worked- but just once - the first time, and after I made some "clever" changes (that I will discuss later), it did not do it again and started spewing a MemoryError. I also rebooted my machine and it's still the same issue. So here's what's going on:

1. There are two data files -
   a) train.parquet 
   b) metadata.csv
2. **metadata.csv** has the information about the type of data **train.parquet** is.
3. There are 4 columns in the `metadata.csv` file, out of which I am interested in three.
4. Due to the type of problem I am working on, I am asked to **transpose** train.parquet. Doing that, the number of *rows* in **train.parquet** WILL match **metadata.csv**. No problems there.
5. So, to begin with, I do `metadata = pd.read_csv("metadata.csv")`
6. Then I do `train = pd.read_parquet("train.parquet", engine = 'pyarrow').T` (.T to transpose)
7. Then, when I try `df = pd.concat([train, metadata.col1, metadata.col2, metadata.col3], axis = 'columns')`, I am thrown a `MemoryError` error.

Here's the 'clever' change I referred to earlier:

1. I initially DID NOT do a `.T` on the training data directly (`train = pd.read_parquet("train.parquet", engine = 'pyarrow').T`)
2. I did `original_data = pd.read_parquet("train.parquet", engine = 'pyarrow')`
3. Then `train = original_data.T` - Does pretty much the same thing, at least to me.
4. After this, when I did `df = pd.concat([train, metadata.col1, metadata.col2, metadata.col3], axis = 'columns')`, it had worked -> This is the only time it worked.
5. But then I realized, I actually wanted `metadata.col1` at the end (as it is the target variable), so I thought I'd rerun it rearranging the order of metadata columns - something like this: `df = pd.concat([train, metadata.col2, metadata.col3, metadata.col1], axis = 'columns')`.
6. Seemed fair.
7. But before I could run that, I tried what I would later regret doing - transposing the dataframe directly (`train = pd.read_parquet("train.parquet", engine = 'pyarrow').T`)
8. After this, each time I try to concatenate the two dataframes, I get the memory error. I have also rebooted my machine.

What can be causing this?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT** - It's a 64 Gb Azure VM.

Comment: Tried with `engine = 'fastparquet'` and it's the same behavior. Although it took significantly longer for the train dataset to load as that. It was faster with `'pyarrow'`

Comment: I created a new conda environment altogether and it's the same thing on that too - MemoryError

Comment: Same thing on a different 64Gb machine.